# Get 2 unknowns from a equation with answer of equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to do a simple math operation, but because I'm bad at math I don't know how can I actually do it
I have this Equation

**out = (var1 - 128) + 64 * (var2 - 1)**

in this Equation both **var1** and **var2** cant go upper then **255**
also **var1** is always higher then **198**
A example of use

**803 = (227 - 128) + 64 * (12 - 1)**

I want to know its possible to get **var1** & **var2** with **out**?
sorry if my question is too bad or I cant tell what I mean right (I also love to do it With programming language

--EDIT--
I can do this in this way, and its almost fast, but Im not sure if its a good way for it our not

```
$var1 = 198
$var2 = 1
$Answer = 0
While $Answer = 0
    $ActualLen = ($var1 - 128) + 64 * ($var2 - 1)
    if $ActualLen = 1600 Then
        ConsoleWrite("CStrlen= " & $var1 & @CRLF & "ExtraStrlen= " & $var2 & @CRLF)
        $Answer = 1
    EndIf
    If $var2 = 255 Then
        $var1 += 1
        $var2 = 1
    Else
        $var2 += 1
    EndIf
WEnd
```

Comment: You cannot in general solve for two unknowns with one equation.

Comment: No, it isn't possible with a single equation. The best you can get is a relation between `var1` and `var2`. This is, the equation reworked.

Comment: Solving for two variables always requires more than just one equation.  Otherwise, you will only get a parametric solution.

Comment: thanks to everyone, but what if i use a static number for var1? maybe number 220, its possible in that way?

Comment: Then it is no longer a variable and you have a linear equation.

Comment: @AndrewChin i add a way to do it, but i think its a very bad way, but its also only way

Comment: Are all your variables always non-negative whole numbers? I think var1 and var2 are byte values in the range 0 to 255.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes exactly, var1 and 2 is some uchar with limit of 255, and yes always non-negative

Comment: Ok. Then you need integer division & remainder. In Python, you'd use `//` and `%`. Several other languages use `%` for remainder too.

Comment: This Python code isn't perfect, but it should get you close to what you want. `var2 = 1 + out // 64; var1 = 128 + out % 64`

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, *normally* one linear constraint on two variables won't do.  In this case, there is one and only one way that the problem is solvable: if var2 is required to be an integer.

Let $a$ denote var1, $b$ denote var2, $c$ denote out.

Reason that the equation is solvable:
In the computation of $c$, $b$ is multiplied by the scalar, $64$.

This means that as $b$ changes value from $n$ to $n+1$ or $n-1$, the value of $64 \times b$ changes value from $64n$ to $64n+64$ or $64n - 64.$

Although there may be other bounds on $b$ (i.e. var2) that is irrelevant.

What is critical is that you have specified that $198 < a \leq 255$, where $a$ is var1.

Since $(255 - 198) < 64,$ once $c$ (i.e. out) is known, there is **one and only one** integer value for $b$ such that $64b$ will result in $a$ being in the range $198 < a \leq 255.$

It is irrelevant whether $a$ (i.e. var1) is required to be an integer.  All that is necessary is that (to summarize)

- var2 is required to be an integer
- var2 has the scalar of 64 applied to it
- var1 has no scalar applied to it (or you can say that the scalar is 1).
- the **width** of the range (i.e. $255 - 198$) of allowable values of var1 is less than 64

---

This begs the question: given $c$ (i.e. out), how do you calculate $a$ and $b$ (i.e. var1 and var2).

The simplest approach is as follows:

Since $c = (a - 128) + 64(b-1)$, you have that 
$c - 64b + 64 = a - 128 \implies$

$$c + 192 - 64b = a.\tag1$$

Therefore, **programatically**, create a guess for $b$ (i.e. $g$) as follows.

Let $g$ represent the computation from the LHS of equation (1), above, **under the assumption** that $b = 0.$

If the result is in the range $198 < g \leq 255$, then, you are done.  Simply set $a = g$.

Suppose that that is not the case.
Then, you simply have to find the right integer value for $b$, so that the result of the LHS computation in equation (1) above will be in the required range of $198 < a \leq 255.$

As your experience/sophistication with math grows, you will find (for yourself) a shortcut to the algorithm that I am going to give you, that you can easily write the code for.

If $g \leq 198$, then, subtract 1 from $b$, and recompute $g$.  Do this in steps, one at a time.  Sooner or later, $g$ will be *in range*, and you will then have solved the problem, because you will have identified the appropriate value for $b$, and because you can then set $a = g.$

If $g > 255$, then follow the algorithm in the above paragraph, in reverse.  Simple add 1 to $b$, recompute $g$, and check if it is in range.  Sooner or later, it will be.

One final note.  It may be strange that I am guaranteeing that an appropriate value for $a$ will be found, even though the width of the range of allowable values for $a$ is **slightly** less than $64$, and the integer value of $64b$ will change by $64$ as $b$ is increased or decreased by $1$.

I am **assuming** that you will only be applying this algorithm to **legitimate** values for $c$ (i.e. out), where $c$ was initially computed by **unknown but legitimate values** for $a,b$.

---

As a simple example of when the above algorithm **will not work**, consider $c$ (i.e. out) $= 66$.

Then, with $b = 0$, your initial value for $g$ is $258$ which is too high.  So, you set $b = +1$ and recompute $g$ and now get $g = 194$, which is too low.  So neither $b = 0$ nor $b = +1$ provides a satisfactory value for $g$, so you can never set $a = g$.

The reason that this happened is that your initial value for $c$ (i.e. out) was **illegitimate**.  That means that $c=66$ could not have been computed by any **legitimate** values for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Didn't read the answer, but you put a lot of effort into it so +1

Comment: Interestingly, this is your $666$th answer